# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

How to resolve this issue

`Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

The site is running good in local host but when publishing the site and checking i am getting the error. Can any one give me a solution for this..

My sample image from `Assembly` folder

[image]

Comment: Check the properties to see if the `Copy Local` value has been set to `true`.

Comment: You need to check this in Visual Studio.  Expand `References`, then locate the `MySql.Data` DLL.  View the properties of the DLL and see if `Copy Local` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DLL either needs to be in the bin folder of the application (or in the same folder) or needs to be installed to the GAC.

Does the MySql DLL come with an installer?

--

This can also happen when the referenced DLL is built with a later version of .Net than the application that is calling it.

Comment: I installed the connector and added as a reference

Comment: Should i add that `MySql.Data.dll` to bin . I already added the reference for the application

Comment: If you added a reference to `MySql.Data.dll`, there should be a copy in your bin.

Comment: Ya there is a copy too in my BIN but still the error remains same

Comment: @Ramakrishna - answer updated with another potential solution